# How to rate Google Play itself?

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-apps

I want to know how we can put review or rate google play store (not their apps)

Comment: Google Play Store is not a regular app, therefore it can not be found in Google Play Store and hence can not be rated there.

Comment: Is there is any place where we can rate it

Comment: There are various APK download sites on the net. I assume some of them allow to rate the apps. Most likely you will find Google Play Store APK here (`com.android.vending`). But rating it there where nobody reads it is in my opinion a bit useless. If you have critics on PlayStore may be you should better write a post on Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Ok... Well thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From [Play Store support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705?hl=en-GB)

> When you can write a review
>
> > You can only review apps you’ve downloaded.

- Since you didn't *download* Google Play, you can't review it. Instead, from the Play Store → Help & Feedback → Send feedback at bottom (via mail) is an option.

Edit: Just found this, it is a better option. Raise it in the [Google Play help community](https://support.google.com/googleplay/community?hl=en)